# Escap XSS attack and face deformation when uploading file in php

Tags: php, html

I have a form that users can upload files like `html, css, php, java, js, txt, javascript` and other files which i included 
But my problem is how can i prevent xss attack or face deformation after successful upload 
Example when user upload files like this

`<input type='text'> //This will show input instead of in plain text
body{display:none!important;} // My document body off`

So i tried to make this php script, it worked very fine while viewing in my site but when i try to open the file in my notepadd++ i don't like the look can anyone suggest me how i can do this better outside my code or fix mine

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!class_exists('DBController')){ require_once("../../_inc/dbcontroller.php"); }

if(isset($_FILES['fileuploader'])){
include_once('../fileextension.php');

        $test = true;

        $FileName = $_FILES['fileuploader']['name'];
        $tmp_name =  $_FILES['fileuploader']['tmp_name'];
        $uploadPath = __DIR__ . '/'.$FileName;
        $currentBas = '';
        $defaultProjecName = '';

        $exetype = pathinfo($FileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $extension = strtolower($exetype);

        if(in_array($extension,$afile)){
        $FTypeof = 'file';
        }
        else if(in_array($extension,$aimg)){
        $FTypeof = 'image';
        }
        else{
        $FTypeof = 'unknown';
        }
        $FDiscripT = 'No available '.($FTypeof == 'unknown') ? '' : $FTypeof.' discription';

      //Here i move the selected file in a directory

        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploadPath);   
        if ($moveResult != true) {
            unlink($uploadPath);
        }else{

            // If file was moved then open file and get the content
        if(file_exists($uploadPath)){
        $fileUploadname = $uploadPath;
        $filechecker = fopen($fileUploadname, "a+");
        $mesure = filesize($fileUploadname);
        if($mesure == 0){
            $sizechecker = 1;
        }
        else{
            $sizechecker = filesize($fileUploadname);
        }
        $get_content_file = fread($filechecker, $sizechecker);
        fclose($filechecker);
        //Then here i use htmlentities to encote the file content
        if(!empty($get_content_file)){
        $sanitize_file = htmlentities($get_content_file);
        $sanitize_file_status = true;
        }

        if($sanitize_file_status == true){
            //Now i put the content back the the file 
            try{
        $openForWrite = fopen($uploadPath, 'w');
        $recreateNewfile = fwrite($openForWrite, $sanitize_file);
        fclose($openForWrite);

        if($recreateNewfile){
            //Then insert the other information to database
            if($test == false){
            $makefile_db = new DBController();
            $makefile_db->prepare("INSERT INTO jailorgchild(jailowner,jailchildbasname,prodefault,jailchillink,jailchilddate,filediscription,contentType)
            VALUES(:jailowner,:jailchildbasname,:SubDif,:jailchillink,:jailchilddate,:FDiscripT,:contentType)");
            $makefile_db->bind(':jailchildbasname', $currentBas);
            $makefile_db->bind(':SubDif', $defaultProjecName);
            $makefile_db->bind(':jailchillink', $FileName);
            $makefile_db->bind(':jailowner', $_SESSION['username']);
            $makefile_db->bind(':jailchilddate', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $makefile_db->bind(':FDiscripT', $FDiscripT);
            $makefile_db->bind(':contentType', $FTypeof);
            $makefile_db->execute(); 
            $filewasmake = $makefile_db->rowCount();
            $makefile_db->free();
            }
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $sanitize_file;                
            //echo 'Unclean Content <br/>'. $get_content_file;          
        }
        }catch(PDOException $e){ 
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }else{
        unlink($uploadPath);
        }   
     }
  }     
}
?>
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<form method="post" action="testuploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileuploader">
<input type="submit" value="load">
</form>
```

**OUTPUT IN NOTEPAD++**

```
&lt;?php if(isset($_GET['postid'])){ echo '&lt;h5 style=&quot;color:
#2f2f2f;&quot;&gt;Related Articles&lt;/h5&gt;&lt;br/&gt;'; &lt;?php } }?&gt;
```

So if another user download it and the file look like that i don't think is good please i need help

Comment: @Bhavin Solanki please help me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php / http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php